# Return Function's Value Issue

Tags: excel, vba

The goal of this code is to count the number of columns on a table of values and return the value of CC from the function FTColSize(CC) to FTLC. The CC returns the correct value but FTLC returns 0.

```
'FTLC ~ First Table Last Column
'CC ~ Column Counter

Sub OneHundred_Percent()
 Dim FTLC%, CC%
  CC = 1
  FTLC = FTColSize(CC)
 Debug.Print "First Table Last Column Coordinate"; FTLC
End Sub

Function FTColSize(CC) As Integer
    Debug.Print "Outside of IF where CC: "; CC
    Debug.Print "Outside of IF statement the value IsEmpty at (1, CC) where CC = "; CC; " is "; IsEmpty(Cells(1, CC).Value)
    If IsEmpty(Cells(1, CC + 1).Value) = False Then
        Debug.Print "Inside If Statement"
        Debug.Print "Incriment CC: "; CC
        CC = CC + 1
        Debug.Print "CC is now "; CC; " inside IF"
        FTColSize (CC)
    Else
        Debug.Print "Inside Else Statement"
        Debug.Print "CC is now "; CC; " inside Else"
        'Return CC
        FTColSize = CC
        Debug.Print FTColSize
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

CC returns as the number of columns in a table in the function procedure. FTLC returns as 0 and I don't understand why. I've tried so many different approaches and when I attempt to return a value the macro tells me it is missing end of statement. does anybody have an idea on how to return CC from the function? I want FTLC to = the result of CC.

Comment: Are you trying to make it recursive?

Comment: Yes it is meant to be recursive

Comment: Then just change `FTColSize (CC)` to `FTColSize = FTColSize(CC)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(1, CC + 1).Value) = False Then
    CC = CC + 1
    FTColSize (CC) ' this is your problem 
    ' change to FTColSize =FTColSize (CC)
Else
    FTColSize = CC
    Exit Function ' you do not need this string
End If
```

When you call the last recursion you get a right value, but the parent recursion overwrites the value. You can see it going step by step while debbuging.